# Problems reading line per line and write with boost::asio::write into serial port device

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

What I`m trying to do:

1. Load and read line in file
2. write to serial port

Problem:
It needs a waiting time otherwise the data is sent too fast and the board can't process the messages one by one.

My Code snippet:

```
//class.cpp
while (!file.atEnd())
    {
        std::string str = file.readLine();
        QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(str);
        writeTextToMessageLog("PRINTF: " + qstr);

        sendCommand(str, str.c_str(), str.size());

        // THE STRAIGHTFORWARD WAY WITH SLEEP
        Sleep(100);
    }     

    void class::sendCommand(const std::string str, const char *buf, const int &size)
{
    size_t bytes = boost::asio::write(m_portConfig, boost::asio::buffer(buf, size));
}
```

That is it basically. I solved it with the SLEEP function, but I want a better way to start writing a new line after my hardware sends a signal or sth. Is there sth like this?

Comment: As far as i know serial ports don't send a response back for receiving data, its more like UDP in that way you just throw data at it and that's it. Consider baud rate before sending data that's a indicator how much data you can throw at it.

Comment: You always have to check if the number of written bytes is equal to the one you wanted to write. And if not then retry to write the remaining ones or use `write_async`.

Comment: Read you sure that the read side is not reading multiple lines in the one read?  If the write side is fast enough, one read can read multiple lines at the same time.  Adding the "pause" between writes may just be acting as a line separator.